# Angular routerLink within [innerHTML]

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have been looking around for a way to enable standard a[href] links to act like routerLinks when loaded dynamically into [innerHTML]. It doesn't seem to be something that works as standard and I couldn't find anything that did what I needed.

I have a working solution but wondered if anybody knows of any better ways to do this or any potential issues I might run into doing it this way.

I am using jQuery from inside my app-routing.module.ts so I declare the variable:

```
declare var $:any;
```

I then find all anchors with the href attribute that do not also have the routerlink attribute. I can then grab the pathname and tell the router to navigate to it on click.

```
$(document).on('click', `a[href]:not("a[routerlink]"):not("a[href^='mailto:']"):not("a[href^='tel:']")`, function(e){
    if(location.hostname === this.hostname || !this.hostname.length){
        e.preventDefault();
        router.navigate([this.pathname]);
    }
});
```

This seems to do the job but I thought there must be a more 'Angular' way of doing this...

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, but you can use `Renderer` and `ElementRef`to add an event listener to the anchor tags as is discussed in [this article](https://fpnotebook.wordpress.com/2017/05/22/angular-24-dynamic-content-woes/).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-html',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.less'],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  private clickListeners: Array<(evt: MouseEvent) => void> = [];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const anchorNodes: NodeList = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a[href]:not(.LinkRef)'); // or a.LinkPage

    const anchors: Node[] = Array.from(anchorNodes);

    for (const anchor of anchors) {
      // Prevent losing the state and reloading the app by overriding the click event
      const listener = this.renderer.listen(anchor, 'click', (evt: MouseEvent) => this.onLinkClicked(evt));
      this.clickListeners.push(listener);
    }
  }

  private onLinkClicked(evt: MouseEvent) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (evt.srcElement) {
      const href = evt.srcElement.getAttribute('href');
      if (href) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(href);
      }
    }
  }
}
```